# Dyck paths without centered tunnels

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

This is from Stanley's Catalan Numbers, problem 36:

[image]

I have difficulty understanding the problem: there is no $L$, $L$'s endpoints lie on $P$ (what is $P$?) and every point of $L$ lies on or below $D$, right? Equivalently, for every such segment $L$, the endpoints are not both on $P$, or some point of $L$ lies above $D$. If we look at the 4th path and take $(i,j)=(2,2)$, then the endpoints are on the path and the segment is above the path? The line $y=2$ is like a tunnel underneath which the path goes. Do I have to read his Enumerative Combinatorics before reading this? There are quite a few terms that I cannot understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your fourth picture, the $L$ you drew is not a problem. It is only a problem if $L$ lies completely _below_ the Dyck path, but your $L$ is completely _above_ the Dyck path. The $L$ you drew resembles a bridge between mountain peaks, but the only thing which is prohibited is tunnels through a mountain range.

Comment: Also, I guess that $D$ is the union of line segments making up the Dyck curve, while $P$ is the set of points in $D$ which have integral $x$ and $y$ coordinates. $D$ is infinite, $P$ is finite.

Comment: I talked with a colleague and figured out that the (non-existing) segment $L$ is under the path so that under it looks like a rectangular tunnel in the cross section of a mountain. And $j$ can be $0$. For example, $udududud$ has a tunnel $i=1,j=0$. Thanks for the comments!